# Chrome, FF, and even Safari crash on file selection

Tags: macos, mac, firefox, google-chrome, safari

MBP running 10.6. This started on the Apache JIRA site. I went to attach a file to a JIRA entry in Chrome 4.0.249.30. Chrome crashed, repeatedly, every time I selected a file from the choose file button.

Then I went to Firefox. I was surprised to get the same result.

Safari worked.

Today I was using http://www.dentbetty.com, and Safari and Chrome both crashed when I tried to upload photos of the dents in my car. Firefox survived.

Something awfully funny is going on here, can anyone recommend a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my SnowLeopard was *not* patched up to date, and all this got better when I updated it.